# Qt annot get metadata from audio file while loading it

Tags: qt, metadata

I have a problem getting metadata from file while loading it from disk. I can play it etc. but can’t get metadata while loading it.

Here is my loading function:

Btw. the “ui->playlistView” element is QTableWidget.

```
void MainWindow::on_actionOpen_triggered()
{
    QFileDialog *fileDialog = new QFileDialog(this);
    QStringList selectedFiles;

    selectedFiles.clear();

    selectedFiles = fileDialog->getOpenFileNames(this, "Select songs", QDir::homePath(), "mp3 files (*.mp3)");
    if(!selectedFiles.empty()){
        playlist->clear();
        ui->playlistView->clear();

        ui->playlistView->setColumnCount(3);
        ui->playlistView->setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, new QTableWidgetItem("Title"));
        ui->playlistView->setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, new QTableWidgetItem("Artist"));
        ui->playlistView->setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, new QTableWidgetItem("Album"));
        ui->playlistView->setRowCount(selectedFiles.count());

        for(int i = 0; i < selectedFiles.count(); i++){
            playlist->addMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile(selectedFiles.at(i)));
            player->setMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile(selectedFiles.at(i)));
            ui->playlistView->setItem(i, 0, new QTableWidgetItem(player->metaData("").toString()));
            ui->playlistView->setItem(i, 1, new QTableWidgetItem(player->metaData("").toString()));
            ui->playlistView->setItem(i, 2, new QTableWidgetItem(player->metaData("AlbumTitle").toString()));
        }
    }

    player->setPlaylist(playlist);
    playlist->setCurrentIndex(0);
}
```

Thanks for help. :)

Comment: Is player a QMediaPlayer or something else object? What do you mean by cannot get the metadata? It seems that you are not playing, and the meta data can be only obtained while playing: `Accessing the currently playing media's metadata (QMediaObject::metaData() and predefined meta-data keys)`

Comment: My bad... yes, player is QMediaPlayer, oh... but how can I obtain the metadata while loading the files? I need to display the playlist in the ui->playlistView for all songs while loading the files, not at the time while playing the song.

Comment: I think meta data is not what you think about meta data. It is meta data about the play status of the song. It is not containing file attributes, and so on as far as I know.

Comment: Sorry I maybe explained it bad... (my english isn't very good), I need to load some songs, and get metadata from them (ie.: song title, album artist, etc.) I know how to get them, but I want to get them while loading the files. I've tried to set player to play currently loaded file and then write the metadata to the table I'm using as a playlist, but it's not working. I have changed my code since I've posted the question, should i edit the question?

Comment: Btw, any reason for not using the [qml component](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtmultimedia-audio.html) for this?

Comment: I like C++ and I'd like to write the program in it. But thanks for help. I will keep trying to make it work as I expect. :)